# How to Change WordPress "Add Media" Pop-up?

Tags: wordpress, media, administration

Is there a solution to change the add Media popup in posts/page Wordpress admin ?

[image: add media popup screenshot]

My dream is to integrate the popup directly in a metabox. The user shouldn't open the popup to manage his media files. And sometimes hide the library and From URL tabs, not always useful...
I'm looking to better manage a product page (for ecommercial website..) and its images.

Just a question :) And maybe a suggestion.
What do you think about that?

Comment: I might recommend you try posting your question on the WordPress site.  You might have better luck with an answer.  Cheers.  Matt

Comment: Yeah sure, I will try :)
If somebody answers me I'll post the solution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate that screen in a couple of ways.

- Using the action hook `admin_head-media-upload-popup`, as seen in [How to Add a Custom Colum on Thickbox Media Gallery Tab?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/53803/12615).
- Or using the filter `media_upload_tabs`: [Remove tabs from media uploader for a CPT](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/46808/12615).

Other solutions/examples and possible hooks can be found with this search query: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=media-upload-popup

Take a look at the plugin [Image Pro](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/image-pro-wordpress-image-media-management-and-resizing-done-right/screenshots/), which seems to meet the requirements.

> Upload, resize, add, change images instantly. Manage your media collection with ease and use it for any post or page. A new way of managing content!

And analyzing the code of the plugin [Faster Image Insert](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/faster-image-insert/screenshots/) can reveal some interesting techniques.

> Fully integrates media manager into editing interface, avoid reloading thickbox pop-up, with enhanced features like multi-insert & mass-editing.

Comment: Oh great !! I will try the hook solution and see all capabilities of this. In same time I have develop my own upload/manage images solution. I'll try to implement it in my WP projects. If it gets work, I will set a Github repository to share it. Thx.

Comment: @E.Rasmussen, you may be interested in this as well: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82260/12615 ;)